# How to verify if CmdLet is present

Tags: powershell

Is there any quick way to check if a Cmdlet is available for me to execute?
I do not want to loop the loaded modules and check if the cmdlet is present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Get-Command <cmdlet name>
```

Comment: For some reasons, I am not able to mark this as correct answer :(